# asp.net compile time error - object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I am getting the following error in the error list of an ASP.NET web site opened in visual studio 2012.

[image]

And in the Error window there is no line number/file name and clicking on the error does not take me to a line of code.

[image]

This is a compile time, not runtime error. The code runs fine on the web server and used to work in VS2005 (on another computer until the drive failed). I just can't get it working in 2012.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a runtime error not a compile time error. Try setting your compiler to break on exceptions.

Comment: @Liath This is a website not a web application project (no project file), where do I set this option?

Comment: In VS go to the menu then Debug, exceptions and it's the inner rows of checkboxes. When debugging your compiler will break when the exception is hit rather than when it's caught.

Comment: Just tried that with all exception types set, tried rebuilding and the website still does not compile. 4 more reputation points and I can show screenshot!

Comment: Enough rep to add images now, question has been updated.

Comment: @Liath this error is from the asp_net compiler, and a bug prevents Visual Studio from treating it as an error. I think it's a valuable question for our site and folks shouldn't be downvoting simply because they see "object reference not set to an instance of an object", making it easy to assume it's an inappropriate novice question.

Comment: @RegEdit thanks for the clarification, glad they got an answer. However I wasn't the downvoter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this in the past and it turned out Visual Studio was reporting an aspnet_compiler error as a "warning". Go to the Error List pane, and at the top there are toggle buttons for Error and Warning. Hit the Warning button till it shows you all the warnings, and you may well find the answer there.

It's also sometimes useful to run aspnet_compiler.exe from the command prompt, to see the output independently from the Visual Studio build.

Comment: I'm getting that, too, and the Warnings aren't telling me much; if interested, see Update 7 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875865/why-am-i-getting-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-but-no