# Why am I getting 'Trim' is not declared with this VB.NET code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, trim

I am trying to get a VB.NET app to compile. Besides the "[elephant in the room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875865/why-am-i-getting-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-but-no)", I'm also getting 7 "*'Trim' is not declared*" errors on code like this:

[image]

...as well as one "'IsNothing' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level." on this line:

```
If IsNothing(memberList) = False Then
```

I don't know VB, so there may be a simple solution to this, but I have no clue what the problems are.

Comment: Why don't you use the NET version of Trim? The one that is part of string class? addr.Trim()

Comment: You might not have the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace included.  That might be the case since it also chokes on `IsNothing`.  The cool kids use the NET counterparts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Trim function requires a reference to *Microsoft.VisualBasic* from the assembly *Visual Basic Runtime Library (in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)*

Usually is preferable to use the native Trim method from the string class and not add a reference to this assembly (mainly used to help porting old VB6 apps)

```
mail.CC.Add(addr.Trim())
```

Notice also that the string.Trim removes other whitespace characters as tabs while the Microsoft.VisualBasic function does not.

Comment: Cool; that gets rid of those six errors; I still have the one for "IsNothing" and the old "Object Ref" one. But this answers my question, so I will mark it as an answer ASAP (in 8 minutes/1:50 PST).

Comment: `IsNothing` ==> `Is Nothing` (not a function) @B.ClayShannon

Comment: When I separate them with a space, it does prevent the earlier err msg, but it brings two new ones: 
Illegal call expression or index expression. -and: "Expression expected"

Comment: `If memberList IsNot Nothing Then ...`  @B.ClayShannon it is not a function

Comment: @Plutonix: Yep, that last did it; I wonder why it ever worked...?!? I assume it did at one time, anyway...

Comment: @B.ClayShannon If it used to have a ref to the VB namespace those legacy functions would work

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `addr.Trim` instead of `Trim(addr)`

Read more about `Trim` in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx)

And you should use

```
If not memberList Is Nothing Then
```

Instead of

```
If IsNothing(memberList) = False Then
```

**Or**

You have to import `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `Left()`, `Mid()`, and `Right()` string functions you might find it easier to convert those too:

`Left(t, l)` becomes `t.Substring(0, l)`

`Mid(t, s, l)` becomes `t.Substring(s-1, l)`

`Right(t, l)` becomes `t.Substring(t.Length - l)`

Often `Left` and `Right` are properties and stop you using the old VB string functions.

Answer (score 0):

`String.Trim` doesn't take a string parameter. It returns a new string in which all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of specified characters from the current String object are removed.

It should be...

```
 addr.Trim()
```