# Why is setting html properties false considered an unexpected token?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, telerik, resharper

I'm unable to build a VB.NET site I've inherited due to a [nebulous error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875865/why-am-i-getting-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-but-no).

Without a clue as to what might be causing it, I turned the hounds of the Czech Republic loose on it (otherwise known as Resharper). It ended up showing me 20 errors and upwards of a thousand other "issues" with the solution:

[image]

Okay, so I'm going after the errors first; ASP Errors first. The first one pointed to this:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="ExportButtonRad" DisabledButtonCssClass="rbDownload' UseSubmitBehavior="false" EnableViewState="false" AutoPostBack="true" CommandName="ExportToExcel" Skin="Default" Visible="false" OnClientClick="document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';" ButtonType="StandardButton" HoveredCssClass="goButtonClassHov" ToolTip="Export" runat="server" Text="Export">
```

...and flagged the following portion:

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

...as an "*Unexpected token*"; so I removed that, and re-ran the Resharper > Inspect > Code Issues in Solution.

Now there are more (not less) ASP Errors, and that same element ("ExportButtonRad") is red-flagged again for the same supposed infraction ("Unexpected token"); this time *EnableViewState="false"* is the culprit or scapegoat.

So I'm afraid that if I remove that, I will have 11 ASP Errors and it will finger some other property set to false as being bogus. I have suspicions this is not the real problem. Does anybody know about any "gotchas" with this that might be the underlying cause of this whack-a-moliation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem will be this:

```
DisabledButtonCssClass="rbDownload'
```

Equalise the quotes.

```
DisabledButtonCssClass="rbDownload"
```