# Is it not possible to add a folder to an ASP.NET bin folder?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, bin

Since I am trying to recreate a legacy ASP.NET project rather than continue down the rabbit hole of trying to figure out why it gives me a no-clues-as-to-where-it-is "[Object reference not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875865/why-am-i-getting-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-but-no)" error, I am trying to add the folders and files from the legacy solution - painstakingly, one at a time - and re/building after each addition to see where the error appears, if it does.

I made it partway, but then tried to add the "Common" folder which is below the "Bin" folder in the legacy project - but it won't let me:

[image]

There's no option afforded for adding a folder there. What can I do in order to proceed?

Comment: If you must do this in this fashion you can navigate to the folder using Windows Explorer and do it using Windows explorer.

However I think you should realy use Visual Studio. You should be able to add the project to an existing solution. If not there must be some issue, and you should try to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do - the screen shot shows what I see when I try to add it in VS.

Comment: if you want to add a folder to the bin directory you can do it in Windows explorer.
I am advising that you add your legacy project using the VS. Right click on the Solution and "add" -> "existing Project"

Comment: I'm fairly certain I would end up with the same problem if I did that; I'm pretty close to getting it all added a piece at a time; so far, so good.

Comment: Hope it works, you can ping me if you run into additional issues.

Comment: Thanks. Here's a weird one that just came up: I added some files beneath a folder named "Mobile" which causes 204 errors such as "Type 'SQLServer' is not defined" Yet the file in which the errors occur is not one of those just added. And I do have DAL05.dll in my references...removing those newly added files from the Mobile folder allows it to build without errors again. More specifically, removing Mobile\Default.aspx and Mobile\Default.aspx.vb clear things up.

Comment: when it comes to assemblies (DLLs) you will have to remove the references and re-add them/

Comment: I did add it, along with some Telerik DLLs. Adding DAL05 solved previous errors, but then when I added the files beneath the Mobile folder, it was as if it couldn't see the reference, as it started complaining about not knowing what SQLServer was.

Comment: Please see my new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942190/why-is-sqlserver-not-recognized-even-though-ive-got-a-reference-to-dal05-dll

Comment: I read your other question. Two suggestions:
1. please read carefully comments that I wrote. especially about removing and  adding references. If you don't know what that means exactly. Please let me know and I will elaborate.

Comment: the other suggestion that I have is more general: If you start a Question thread on one topic you should try to stick to it. I think you should stick to the issue or indicate that specific question was solved.

I also really think that you should attempt to add the project through VS.

Comment: @DaniDev: I think I know what you mean by removing and adding back references, but doing so made no difference in this case. I have seen that work before when working on a Compact (Bomb-packed) framework project, though.

Comment: alright good luck.